# Adding days to an interval with postgres

Tags: postgresql

i want in postgres add in a column daterange(called period) some days.

for example, if daterange is

26-09-2014 : 28-09-2014

i want add 2 days and the result must be another daterange

28-9-2014 : 30-09-2014

How can i do?
i try

```
select PERIOD, PERIOD + '2 day' from mytable
```

Comment: Is PERIOD a custom data type?

Comment: @greg: the first line says that it's a `daterange`

Comment: missed that, i didn't know there was a 'range'.

Comment: @greg: This has been added in Postgres 9.2. They are pretty powerful I think there is no other DBMS that offers something like that - especially combined with exclusion constraints: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: period is the name of the column and it's type is datarange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the value to each element and then create a new daterange out of that:

```
select daterange(lower(period) + 2, upper(period) + 2)
from mytable;
```

Note that you can not add an `interval` (e.g. `interval '2' day`) to the `date` value because that returns a `timestamp` and thus that value cannot be converted to a `daterange`

Answer (score 1):

```
select daterange(lower(r) + 2, upper(r) + 2)
from (values
    (daterange(current_date, current_date + 2))
) s(r);
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2014-09-28,2014-09-30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE t (period daterange);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('[2014-09-26, 2014-09-28]'::daterange);
SELECT period,
       lower(period),
       upper(period),
       daterange(lower(period), (upper(period)+INTERVAL '2 days')::date, '[]')
  FROM t;

         period          |   lower    |   upper    |        daterange
-------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------
 [2014-09-26,2014-09-29) | 2014-09-26 | 2014-09-29 | [2014-09-26,2014-10-02)
```

Note, that although I've specified `2014-09-28` to be a bounding upper value, unbounded `2014-09-29` is reported.